# The DP point collector - Dynamic Programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

We got this question in a Dynamic Programming assignment:

> In the new computer game "The crazy DP point collector", the player
>   direct an avatar along `n` rooms labeled `1,...,n`. The game lasts `T`
>   time units. The player can skip a room, or spend in a room exactly 1,
>   2 or 4 time units. For each room `1<=i<=n` and each `j` that is
>   `{1,2,4}`, we are given the value `C(i,j)` denoting how many points
>   the player can collect in room `i` in `j` minutes. It is known that
>   for all `i`
>
> ```
> C(i, 1) <= C(i, 2) <= C(i,4).
> ```
>
> 1. What is the maximal number of points the player can collect in the game?
> 2. How many time units should the player spend in each room in order to achieve it?

I was thinking about a 2 dimensional array where the rows represent the rooms and the columns represent the time units. A sub-problem would be "What is the best amount of points I can collect in T-x time".

After a long brain storming I am stuck on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can the player skip more than one room?

Comment: Yes. I believe he can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming a few things - correct me if I'm wrong:

1. the player needs to walk through the rooms in this order, i.e. she cannot jump back from room 9 to room 8 even if 8 was skipped before; so a valid path for [four rooms](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113101/) can be e.g. any of

   - `1-2-3-4`
   - `1-3`
   - `2-4`
2. there are no penalties, only rewards i.e. `C(i,j)>=0` for all `i,j`

A simpler sub-problem would be "What is the highest amount of points I can make after `t` time steps, ending in room number `k`?". Let's call the solution to this sub-problem `F(k,t)`. How did we get here?

Well, if we are in room `k`, then we must have spent 1, 2 or 4 time units sitting here. Our "best predecessor" is then a room `k' < k` we've been to just `dt = 1, 2` or `4` steps ago:

[image]

Since we can skip any number of rooms, we can start in any of those with a total cost of 0:

[image]

Once we have all values of the table `F` we pick the final room to be

[image]

where `F(K,T)` is the answer to question (1). For the answer to question (2) we reconstruct the best path by following the backpointers we stored while evaluating the maximization over best predecessors. I omit this rather technical step, but let me know if you want to go into detail here.

There are `n*T` sub-problems we need to evaluate and each term in the table `F` can be constructed by considering up to `n` possible predecessor rooms at 3 possible time steps in the past (1, 2 and 4 steps ago), so that the total number of operations will be proportional to `3*T*n^2` (I think you can come up with an implementation that gets rid of the `3` by storing some of the intermediate maximum values).